# Configuring Eclipse to allow Fiddler to intercept requests

Tags: eclipse, fiddler

In Eclipse there are two places that I've attempted to configure so that Fiddler can intercept the HTTP/HTTPS requests that I'm sending out:

1. `Windows > Preference > General > Network Connections` - I've tried Native/Direct/Manual
2. In VM arguments, I add the following `-DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DproxyPort=8888`

EDIT: I've tried the new properties suggested by rgerganov as well.

I haven't touched any "network" related settings in Fiddler and I've set it to monitor all processes.

I tried with Wireshark and I was able to intercept the requests with no modifications to Eclipse but information presented in Wireshark is too in-depth and I don't need most of the details provided by Wireshark.

EDIT: Here's the sample code which I'm trying:

```
public static void doPOST() {
    String post_url = "https://lookup.mxtelecom.com/USLookup";

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion( params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1 );
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset( params, "UTF-8" );
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue( params, true );

    SchemeRegistry supportedSchemes = new SchemeRegistry();
    supportedSchemes.register( new Scheme( "https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443 ) );
    supportedSchemes.register( new Scheme( "http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80 ) );

    ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager( params, supportedSchemes );
    HttpClient m_Client = new DefaultHttpClient( ccm, params );

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( post_url );

    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add( new BasicNameValuePair( "something", "useful" ) );

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
      @Override
      public String handleResponse( HttpResponse response ) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        if ( response.getEntity() != null ) {
          return EntityUtils.toString( response.getEntity() );
        }

        return null;
      }
    };

    try {
      UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity( postParameters, "UTF-8" );
      httpPost.setEntity( entity );
      results = m_Client.execute( httpPost, responseHandler );

    } catch ( ClientProtocolException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Eclipse Build id: 20100218-1602 // 3.5.2.R35x
Fiddler2 v2.3.2.6
jdk1.6.0_21

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I failed to mention how the connection was made which made answering this question harder that necessary - jdramaix's answer however pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`HttpClient` needs to be made aware of the proxy information. Several approaches can be used:

See 2.7 in HTTP Component's [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html):

1. "Connect to the target host via a proxy is by setting the default proxy parameter"

   ```java
   DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

   HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8888);

   httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
   ```
2. Using "the standard JRE proxy selector to obtain proxy information"

   ```java
   DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

   ProxySelectorRoutePlanner routePlanner = new ProxySelectorRoutePlanner(
               httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry(), ProxySelector.getDefault());

   httpclient.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);
   ```

   and then adding the following as VM arguments:

   ```java
   -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888
   ```
3. Custom `RoutePlanner` implementation (I did not explore this option)

Answer (score 5):

You have many possibility to configure proxy in java :

1. Using system properties

   - via VM arguments (assuming you want to enable proxy for http and https traffic) :

`java -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888`

- via System properties :

  ```
  // Get system properties
  Properties sysProperties = System.getProperties();
  // Specify proxy settings
  sysProperties.put("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
  sysProperties.put("https.proxyPort", "8888");
  sysProperties.put("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
  sysProperties.put("http.proxyPort", "8889");
  ```

The "disavdantage" of this method : once the proxy is set for a protocol, all connection for that protocol will use the proxy

2. java.net.Proxy : available since java 1.5. Allow you to specify a proxy configuration to use for opening a connection

   ```
   SocketAddress addr = new  InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8888);
   Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
   URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
   InputStream in = url.openConnection(proxy).getInputStream();
   ```
3. ProxySelector class : available since Java 1.5. allow you to select a proxy by URI ! It's an abstract class, a simple implementation returning your proxy for all http and https connection looks like :

   ```
   public static class MyProxySelector extends ProxySelector {
       private List<Proxy> proxy;
       private List<Proxy> noProxy;

       MyProxySelector() {
           proxy = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
           SocketAddress addr = new  InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8888);
           proxy.add(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr));

           noProxy = new ArrayList<Proxy>();
           noProxy.add(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
       }

       public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
           System.err.println("Connection to the proxy for uri :"+uri);
           if (uri == null) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI can't be null.");
           }
           String protocol = uri.getScheme();

           if ("http".equalsIgnoreCase(protocol) || "https".equalsIgnoreCase(protocol)) {
               //if http or https connection, return our proxy config
               return proxy;
           } else {
               // Otherwise don't use a proxy
               return noProxy;
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
           System.err.println("Connection to the proxy failed !");
           //throw exception or do some stuff...
       }
   }
   ```

And set your proxy selector as default proxy selector

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
     ProxySelector.setDefault(new MyProxySelector());
     //...
    }
```

I prefer this last mechanism because you can put some logging and see wath Java is doing !

### Important remark :

By default, Fiddler captures only traffic coming from web-browsers !! Change that to capture traffic of all processes : [image: bottom toolbar]
<sub>(source: [comexis.eu](http://julien.comexis.eu/fiddler.jpg))</sub>

Comment: to go deeply : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/proxies.html

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely a big push in the right direction. I did check to make sure Fiddler was checking for "All Processes". Your ProxySelector got me thinking and looking further in Apache's HTTPComponent documentation and I did find code similar to what you provided and it works.

Answer (score 2):

The second method should work, however the properties are `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) and these are definitely the properties to be using but unfortunately nothing is showing up in Fiddler2.

Answer (score 2):

Also, in Fiddler if you need to capture All Processes from a HTTPS connection, then you need to go to the Tools menu - Fiddler Options - HTTPS - check the 'Decrypt HTTPS traffic' and select '...from all processes'.

Selecting the 'All Processes' from Fiddler's status bar apparently is just for HTTP connections.

Answer (score 1):

JVM parameter of proxy host and proxy port can be used. At the same time, Fiddler certificate needs to be installed to sniffer https connections.